# Trying to run play application in console on heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to start a play application in a console on heroku using this line of code:

```
new play.core.StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))
```

Unfortunately it seems to be having a problem connecting to my database. I'm using postgres. Here's my configuration from application.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}
db.default.user=myusername
db.default.password=mypassword
```

My app is able to access the database through regular use. Here's the error i'm getting:

c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.Message:Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]

Comment: You're trying to connect to a localhost database on Heroku? That's not going to work..

Comment: Yep, that's probably an issue. I've updated it to use the data base url environment variable `db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}`. I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: Why the question mark? Also, what about the database username and password environment variables?

Comment: Not sure about the question mark. I can remove it. Does heroku have username and password environment variables? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Ah, perhaps they're all contained within the URL. In which case, the variables in your application.conf will be interfering. Perhaps pull the username/password from the db url and create env vars for them with `heroku config`, and set `db.default.user` and `db.default.password` equal to them in your Procfile.